# Android scroller fling

Tags: android, touch, scroller

I hava a problem with a scroller.

```
    @Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    Log.d(TAG, "compute: " + mScroller.computeScrollOffset());
    mScroller.fling(0, 0, 0, 1000, 0, 0, 0, 2000);
    invalidate();
    ...
```

But i can't see any fling effect on touch, what am I doing wrong?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You simply need to call `mScroller.computeScrollOffset()` directly before you access the current x and y values with mScroller.getCurrX/Y(). The scroller doesn't scroll a view itself, it just provides the values you manually need to apply.